# External Css doesn't work while i have linked the file correctly

Tags: html, css

I am new in coding in HTML and CSS and I have the following problem. While I have coded in CSS and I have linked my CSS file into HTML still the website isn't designed. Any help

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/Konstantinos.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1> Konstantinos Bantelis </h1>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr> <td> <nav> <a href="One"> One </a></nav></td><td><nav> <a href="Two"> Two </a></nav> </td> <td> <a href="Three"> Three </a></td> <td> <a href="Four"> Four</a></td> </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </header>
</body>
```

**CSS code:**

```
h1 {
  color:#FF0000;
}

header {
  margin: 4%;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

Comment: What does your file tree look like?

Comment: This questtion comes along several times a week here, and the problem is *always*  the file path for the link to the stylesheet...

Comment: Do check for error in console

Answer (score 3):

You can check this

- Check your file name and folder name isn't wrong(check mistake of capital letter or small letter)
- Check if you are keeping your html in a another folder(if then you should add ../ to your folder like this `../Css/Konstantinos.css`)
- Check if you accidentally deleted your file or renamed it
- Check in your webpage's console(right-click and inspect) if you have a 404 error